# If I want to get the progress of an image download using NSURLSession, do I have to use the download methods over data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

NSURLSession has `NSURLSessionDataTask` and `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` and I'm more of a fan of data, as I don't need to retrieve it from the file system.

The [NSURLSessionDownloadTaskDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013444-CH1-SW6) has a method for retrieving progress on the download, though it doesn't seem the data counterpart does. If I want download progress, am I required to use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`?

If so, I understand `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` stores the file downloaded and then you retrieve it. Does this directory where files are stored need to emptied occasionally, or is it just a temp store that gets removed as soon (or soon after) accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **AFNetworking** for that. The **AFHTTPRequestOperation** allows you to set a block for tracking progress.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:YOUR_URL_REQUEST];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
{
     // Completion code.
} 
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
{      
     // Error handling code.
}];
```

Here is how you can track progress:

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) 
{
    float progress = ((float)((int)totalBytesWritten) / (float)((int)totalBytesExpectedToWrite));

   // Track the progress here

}];
```